# Batch script to merge files using copy command in numerical order

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, ms-dos

Would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this request.

I need a dynamic batch script which can do the below command for **ANY number of files**:

```
Copy 1.txt + 2.txt + 3.txt + 4.txt newfile.txt
```

If I have the following files:

1.txt

2.txt

3.txt

...so on

And I try: `Copy *.txt newfile.txt`
It does not sort correctly when merging.
It actually ends up doing this: `Copy 3.txt + 4.txt + 2.txt + 1.txt newfile.txt`

Also, I need it to use the **copy** command and NOT the type command.

I could not find a proper way of doing this as most of the FOR loop examples online use TYPE and that is not suitable for what I'm trying to achieve.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. As per [on-topic], your question belongs on http://stackoverflow.com/ rather. However, this is weird : `Copy *.txt newfile.txt` command merges files in alphabetical order on my Windows 8, listing copied files as in `dir /B /O:N *.txt`. Please [edit] your question and share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Appreciate your quick response and apologies for posting here :) Have updated the question.

Comment: I'm also curious why your files are not copied in order. Its possible that the COPY command is following the DIR ordering settings. To test that set the DIRCMD environment variable to order your files by name using `set DIRCMD=/OGN`. Then try your copy command.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe that `copy` would change sort order of merged files. However, next *self_explaining* script could help:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

pushd d:\bat\files\folder

REM echo(&echo SHOW files to be merged in different sort order 
REM erase newfile.txt 2>NUL
REM @ECHO ON
REM @for %%G in (
REM   "/-C" "/O:N" "/O:S" "/O:E" "/O:D /T:C" "/O:D /T:W"
REM   ) do dir %%~G *.txt|findstr "\.txt$"
REM @ECHO OFF

echo(&echo RESULT: copy *.txt newfile.txt
erase newfile.txt 2>NUL
rem (optional): to throw away trailing `Ctrl+Z`, use `/B` switch as follows:
rem copy /Y *.txt newfile.txt /B  
@ECHO ON
copy /Y *.txt newfile.txt
findstr "^" *.txt
@ECHO OFF

echo(&echo(&echo RESULT: merge *.txt in defined order: change `/O` switch
echo(
type nul> newfile.txt
set /A "_files=0"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
  dir /B /O:N *.txt
  ') do @if not "%%G"=="newfile.txt" (
            echo(%%~G
            set /A "_files+=1"
            copy /Y newfile.txt + %%~G newfile.txt /B >NUL
        )
echo       %_files% file^(s^) merged.
rem (optional): to add trailing `Ctrl+Z`, remove `REM` in next line  
REM copy newfile.txt + NUL newfile.txt >NUL
@ECHO ON
findstr "^" *.txt
@ECHO OFF
popd
```

Note that `REM`-commented code snippet following `pushd` command would show  files to be merged in different sort order if uncommented (all 7 `REM` removed). I keep it here for debugging purposes.

**Result**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\1002948.bat

RESULT: copy *.txt newfile.txt

==> copy /Y *.txt newfile.txt
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
        1 file(s) copied.

==> findstr "^" *.txt
1.txt:1111
2.txt:2
3.txt:333
4.txt:44
newfile.txt:1111
newfile.txt:2
newfile.txt:333
newfile.txt:44
newfile.txt:→

RESULT: merge *.txt in defined order: change `/O` switch

1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
      4 file(s) merged.

==> findstr "^" *.txt
1.txt:1111
2.txt:2
3.txt:333
4.txt:44
newfile.txt:1111
newfile.txt:2
newfile.txt:333
newfile.txt:44

==>
```

Here trailing `→` rightwards arrow symbol in `newfile.txt` represents `EOF` (end of file, hexadecimal `0x1A`), i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.